# Take thumb impression android

Tags: android

I need to take thumb impression in my android pad application.When the user press the thumb on the pad screen his thumb impression i need to get in JPEG format image.Please any one know replay.

Comment: did  you got the solution  if yes post it .

Comment: good question...if found any please post.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this can't be done.
Capacitative screens (which would detect a thumb) are not sensitive enough to get a fingerprint. Cool idea though... Maybe consider using the camera (though it would have to be pretty high quality).

Comment: niky may well be right that "The camera on the phone cannot capture macros unless you mount a microscope lense" and it's true that there would be APIs to help you do this sort of thing. Check the documentation for using the camera though and have a go. Maybe you can write the APIs... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you one alternative rather than taking finger print .. There few apps developed on android which basically recognizes your pressure not your fingerprint and it resembles that they are taking your finger print.

Have a look at it.. I don't know if it solves your problem. !

[5 Best fingerprint lock app for Android](http://www.techshout.com/features/2012/02/best-fingerprint-lock-apps-for-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Android does not do fingerprint recognition. If you are talking about those apps that "claim" to do it by you holding your finger against the screen ... its a bit of a con. They don't really scan your finger print ... they are just testing area and pressure (if that).

First, don't ask for code. This place is not for giving out code but snippet or help. You're asking for someone to publish complex code here...that's ridiculous.

Second, if there was a library available for FingerPrint recognition. I highly doubt you could even do anything with it. Why?

Phones don't have hardware to capture fingerprints. A screen cannot capture images but only pressure levels and they aren't really accurate too. The camera on the phone cannot capture macros unless you mount a microscope lense.

So if you really want my advice, give up on it. With the current hardware available it is not coming soon to android. When there will be hardware I believe there will be an api provided for it.

What you can do on the other hand is voice recognition, face recognition. I don't have any idea how it can be done but the hardware is there. You could even make a hand recognition.

Finger prints forget it.

Comment: Don't mistake me. i am not ask for code just let me know it is possible or not. when it is possible let me know on what basis you tell that.